# Wordpress Custom Post Types with a page as a parent?

Tags: wordpress

I have a lot of custom type items in my new WP project, and for navigation reasons, I want to make the parent to some of them a Wordpress page. The problem is that apparently, Wordpress does not let you establish parent-child relationships between items with different post type.

Is there anyway to override this? I am using Wordpress 3.1

Answer (score 1):

What functionality of the "page" do you need the post type parent to have? I'm guessing that you just want to be able to edit the page title & content from the backend.

If that is the case, try the following:

1. Create a custom "archives" page for each post type (http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Type_Templates)
2. Create a corresponding page in Wordpress to handle the title & content
3. Using the custom archive template, programmatically tell the template to display the title & content from the corresponding page.

Code:

```
<?php $archive_post=get_post(YOUR_CORRESPONDING_PAGE_ID); ?>

<h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo apply_filters("the_title",$archive_post->post_title);?></h1>

<div class="entry-content"><?php echo apply_filters("the_content",$archive_post->post_content);?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the archive-[post-type].php files to show as archive or single-[post-type].php to show indiviual posts.